# bash script to check if input has an @

Tags: bash

Hi I am trying to write a bash script in which the input is checked to see if it contains an @ symbol, I'm am relatively new to bash so please forgive any/all errors!
So far I have:

```
var1="@"
var2="INPUT"

echo "input"
read INPUT

if [[ "$var2" == "$var1" ]]; then
echo "pass"
else
echo "fail"
fi
```

Comment: Please make a note: Pure programming questions such as these are probably better suited for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), even though they're somewhat on topic here if the system used is Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried posting on stack overflow but kept getting errors saying the post wasn't structured properly/incorrect grammar? I checked structure and grammar several times and kept getting red lines under nearly every word and it wouldn't allow me to post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `bash` code reads input and signals "Pass" if the input contains an `@` symbol:

```
read -p "Input: " var
[ "${var//[^@]/}" ] && echo Pass || echo Fail
```

Notes:

- `[ "$var" ]` is a bash test.  It returns true if the string `$var` is non-empty.
- One of bash's features is pattern substitution.  It looks like `${var//pattern/string}`.  It replaces every occurrence of `pattern` in `var` with `string`.  In our case, `pattern` is `[^@]` which is a regular expression which matches every character *except* `@`.  Thus `${var//[^@]/}` returns an empty string unless `var` contains at least one `@`.
- We combine the above two:

  ```
  [ "${var//[^@]/}" ]
  ```

  This test succeeds only if `${var//[^@]/}` is non-empty and `${var//[^@]/}` is non-empty only if `var` contains at least one `@`.

#### Using an explicit if-then-else:

```
read -p "Input: " var
if [ "${var//[^@]/}" ]
then
    echo Pass
else
    echo Fail
fi
```

#### POSIX Shell

The following works under `dash` (`/bin/sh`) and should work under any POSIX shell:

```
printf "Input: "
read var
case "$var" in
    *@*) echo Pass
        ;;
    *) echo Fail
        ;;
esac
```

The POSIX shell does not support the `-p` option to [`read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html).  So, a combination of `printf` and `read` are used instead.  Also, lacking advanced variable expansion features of `bash`, the `case` statement can be used for glob matching.

#### Android Shell

Using the default shell on my android, the following works:

```
echo -n "Input: "; read var
if ! [ "${var//@/}" = "$var" ]
then
    echo Pass
else
    echo Fail
```

Comment: Thanks John, could you please post answer in releation to my code? Being so new I'm still finding it hard to interpret commands/structure... Sorry

Comment: @JONAS402 I wrote it again with an explicit if-then-else.  Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks so much, much easier to read atlthough I seem to be having a -p no coprocess error (although I am using on android as I am away from my linux machine)

Comment: @JONAS402 On my android, I observe the same error.  By contrast, `bash` supports `-p`.  The default android shell will also have problems with the pattern substitution as well.

Comment: OK, well at least it's not just me! Thank you so much will try this tomorrow, have you found an easy to use bash shell good for scripting on android?

Comment: It seems to be possible to install [bash on android](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash) but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Any suggestions for reasons why this answer received a downvote?

Comment: @John1024 I don't know why this would've gotten a downvote. But you might want to expand it slightly to explain the shortcomings of `cmd1 && cmd2 || cmd3`--i.e., that this idiom for a ternary conditional operator breaks when faced with a `cmd2` that exits unsuccessfully, [which actually *can* happen with `echo`](https://askubuntu.com/a/622024). This is really only okay here because the command on the right-hand side is *also* `echo`. I'm *not* suggesting this answer needs a lengthy explanation (like the one in my post), but detailing how `&&` and `||` work in your example would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Though you have the option of using inbuilt shell functionality to check if the user's input contained `@` (which is well documented in the other answers), another reasonable way to do it is with the external [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/grep.1.html) utility:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -erp '> '
if grep -q @ <<<"$REPLY"; then
    echo pass
else
    echo fail
fi
```

Passing the `-q` flag to `grep` prevents it printing matching lines. (It also keeps it from reading any more lines after finding a match, but that doesn't make a difference here as there is only one line of input.)

It's tempting to shorten the `if` construct to something like `grep -q @ <<<"$REPLY" && echo pass || echo fail`, but I have deliberately avoided doing so:

- **In this case**, that's probably okay, since the only way the wrong word prints is if `pass` was supposed to be printed and `echo` failed to print it. Then, presumably, echo would fail to print `fail` as well.
- While short-circuit `&&` and `||` are often themselves appropriate (and I frequently use them to abbreviate an `if` *without* an `else` clause), using them together as though they were [a ternary *if* operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) is not really a good habit. While some commands cannot [fail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status), `echo` *can*.
- If the user [redirects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29) your script's output to an unwritable file or device, or uses it in a broken [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29), echo and other commands that output text can return failure, causing the `&&` expression to fail and the right side of the `||` expression to execute.
- You can test the behavior of a script in the presence of an unwritable output device by running it with `>/dev/full`.

That script uses a few bash features:

- `-e` enables GNU readline, so the user can move the cursor left and right with the arrow keys to edit their input while entering it.
- In bash, `read` automatically puts the user's input in the `REPLY` variable if no variable was given.
- A [here string](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) with `<<<` is a convenient way to pass the user's input to `grep`.
- Bash and *some* other Bourne-style shells such as dash accept `-p`. But [POSIX-compatible shells need only understand `-r`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//utilities/read.html). And in some, like ksh, `-p` has a different meaning.
  (Thanks to [geirha](https://askubuntu.com/users/9016/geirha) for pointing out both that [`-p` is sometimes absent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544545/bash-script-to-check-if-input-has-an/622024?noredirect=1#comment880449_622024) and that [it doesn't always mean "prompt."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544545/bash-script-to-check-if-input-has-an/622024?noredirect=1#comment880482_622024))

If you want a script that's portable to on other OSes that might not have bash installed, you can use:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

printf '> '
read -r line

if printf '%s' "$line" | grep -q @; then
    echo pass
else
    echo fail
fi
```

If you like, you can skip storing the user's input in a variable by reading it with [`head`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/head.1.html) instead of `read`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

printf '> '
if head -1 | grep -q @; then
    echo pass
else
    echo fail
fi
```

As [geirha mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544545/bash-script-to-check-if-input-has-an#comment880449_622024), `head -n 1` might be considered better syntax as `head -1` is [officially obsolete](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/head-invocation.html) (though current `sed` implementations, or at least GNU sed, support `-1` in their latest versions, while some very old `sed` implementations do not support `-n 1`).

As [the `head` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/head-invocation.html) says, you can use `sed` instead for maximum portability.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

printf '> '
if sed 1q | grep -q @; then
    echo pass
else
    echo fail
fi
```

Comment: POSIX `read` only has one option, `-r`, so the first sh example should use `printf` to print the prompt. And using `head -1` is obsoleted in favour of `head -n 1`

Comment: @geirha Yes, you are right. Thanks! I've fixed the unportable use of `read -r`. As for `head -1`, are you sure `head -n 1` should be considered objectively better? Is there a plan to remove `-countoptions` from forthcoming versions of current `head` implementations? My understanding is `-n 1` also doesn't work on some implementations, and that to maximize portability [one might use `sed 1q` instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198176/11938). ...Well, on reflection it's best I not run the risk of mis-advising people. I've edited again to explain the issue (and to add the `sed 1q` way).

Comment: See [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html#tag_20_57_18) about the rational for removing the **-number** form. I doubt any existing implementations of head will remove it though. There's still a lot of code that use the "old" style.

Comment: `ksh`'s `read` also has a `-p` option, but there it means "read from coprocess" instead of "use this as prompt".

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way in bash is to use the pattern matching feature of `[[ ... ]]`.

```
#bash
read -rp "Input: " input
if [[ $input = *@* ]]; then
    printf '<%s> contains @\n' "$input"
fi
```

For `sh` scripts you can use `case` instead.

```
#sh
printf 'Input: '
read -r input
case $input in
    *@*) printf '<%s> contains @\n' "$input" ;;
esac
```

See also the [Tests and Conditionals](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals) chapter of the Bash Guide.

Answer (score -1):

In newer versions of bash, you should be able to use a *regular expression match* via the `=~` extended test operator:

```
$ read -p "input: " input
input: quertyuiop 
$ if [[ $input =~ \@ ]]; then echo "match"; else echo "no match"; fi
no match
$ 
$ read -p "input: " input
input: qwerty@uiop
$ if [[ $input =~ \@ ]]; then echo "match"; else echo "no match"; fi
match
```

An alternative that should work in any POSIX compliant system is to use `expr` e.g. in the `dash` shell:

```
$ read input
qwertyuiop
$ if expr "$input" : '.*@.*' > /dev/null; then echo 'match'; else echo 'no match'; fi
no match
$ 
$ read input
qwerty@uiop
$ if expr "$input" : '.*@.*' > /dev/null; then echo 'match'; else echo 'no match'; fi
match
$
```

Comment: Cheers guys! You've given me alot to think about!

Comment: Would I be right in saying I could use these expressions with a while or until loop?